# Snow Leopard installer ISO on USB flash drive

Tags: macos, mac, snow-leopard, usb, startup

I have the setup ISO file for my Mac OS X Snow Leopard.
I need to be able to boot this and install it to a USB drive (from a windows pc by booting the USB drive).

I can't run it in a virtual environment and I can't burn it to a DVD (it doesn't work for some reason. It only makes a ~120KB of data on the DVD).

So, I need to make a bootable USB installer from the Snow Leopard ISO so I can boot that and install it to another USB/hard drive (this has to be done from a windows machine). 
I have tried [Multiboot ISO](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/tag/multiboot-iso/) but it requires the USB to be formatted as FAT32 and as the ISO is over 4GB, this won't work.

How can I create the bootable installer?

Comment: Just to be sure that we get it right: You want to create a bootable USB stick installer for OS X SL using a Windows machine?

Comment: That is correct.
And I have the ISO for SL.

Answer (score -1):

you can try with transmac to do this